# bacon.js - get value of stream/property

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

Probably it's simple question, but I can't resolve my problem. I have two streams and want mapping second stream by negative value of first stream.

jsfiddle - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/znudwwaj/2/)

```
var price = change.map(1).scan(10, plus)
var money = buy.map(-price).merge(sale.map(price)).scan(100, plus);
```

Comment: `price` is a property, not a value. Try `price.map(function(p){ return -p; })`

Comment: is it just me or is this really over complicated ? :o

Comment: It's not that complicated, with a bit of practice you get a feeling to separate the eventstreams / properties and the values. Using named functions and streams helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is basically what bergi said in the comments.

```
var price = change.map(1).scan(10, plus)
var purchasePrice = price.map(function(p) { return -p }).sampledBy(buy)
var salePrice = price.sampledBy(sale)
var money = purchasePrice.merge(salePrice).scan(100, plus)
```

I used [`property.sampledBy(stream)`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#property-sampledby) instead of [`stream.map(property)`](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js#stream-map) - they do the same thing, but here I think it's clearer to use `sampledBy`.